# How do i render react component stored as string in variable?

Tags: html, rendering, reactjs, jsx

I have Code [Login code](http://pastebin.com/3stWP1F9)
What i actually need, is to store a whole login.js react component file as  a string in the database and then fetch file from db and render that to browser.

I can not render from server since it will take lot of request to do that because the file will be edited by user also will not be real time. Please guide me.

Can it be possible?

Comment: This is not going to work as you expect it to. You are stringifying something that is already a string. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you actually need to strictly store it as a string .

Comment: @TimoSta Please refer the edited question

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Please refer the edited question

Answer (score 0):

It is usually frowned upon and should only be done if you are fully in control of what goes inside the string variable. But you can do something like this:

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ __html: A } />;`

you wouldn't need to do any of the json stringify or json parse stuff either just would send in as a regular html string.

here is more info on it from React docs https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

The reason you need to ensure you are in control of what goes in it is because there is no sanitization of the html and it could be a huge security issue. But if you know exactly what will go in or out of it then there isn't an issue there.

Comment: Let say i have a whole `.js` that have `imports , react life cycle` method, render method and all are in form of a string then what should i do to render.

Comment: Why would you have those in string format? React definitely doesn't provide a way for you to do that and I'm pretty sure the solution for that, if possible, wouldn't be straightforward or clean.

Comment: I have edited question please have a look at the line added above that is my exact use case.

Comment: I’m curious if you ever found an answer to this. I was thinking it would be cool to store code snippets into a DB, and render them into my application and provide support for imports.